# How to combine multiple parse queries at once

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have two parse queries which I want to be evaluated at single click of a button.
I  have two classes in Parse.I want to check for both the things at once.
My queries are:

```
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query =ParseQuery.getQuery("Login");
                query.whereEqualTo("x",X);
                query.whereEqualTo("y",Y);
```

At the same time of login I am checking for a relationship between two entities.
My second query is:

```
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query1 =ParseQuery.getQuery("UserData");
                query.whereEqualTo("entity1",entity1);
                query.whereEqualTo("entity2",entity2);
```

Now if both the queries are successful then user is able to process the app.
How can I combine the two queries so that both the queries must be successful

Comment: Are you sure your example code is correct, because both queries are looking at the same table 'Login'. So I am not to sure why you need two queries?

Comment: I am sorry I have corrected the mistake.

Answer (score 11):

Use a compound query. Example below is taken from Parse Docs at www.parse.com

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> lotsOfWins = ParseQuery.getQuery("Player");
lotsOfWins.whereGreaterThan(150);

ParseQuery<ParseObject> fewWins = ParseQuery.getQuery("Player");
fewWins.whereLessThan(5);

List<ParseQuery<ParseObject>> queries = new ArrayList<ParseQuery<ParseObject>>();
queries.add(lotsOfWins);
queries.add(fewWins);

ParseQuery<ParseObject> mainQuery = ParseQuery.or(queries);
mainQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(List<ParseObject> results, ParseException e) {
    // results has the list of players that win a lot or haven't won much.
  }
});
```

Comment: This should be accepted as answer so others can get help. In my case it worked perfectly, simple and best answer

Answer (score 1):

You can create CountDownLatch and initialize it with number of your queries. Then each query will countdown it on completing its task.

```
final CountDownLatch mCountDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(2);
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query =ParseQuery.getQuery("Login");
    query.whereEqualTo("x",X);
    query.whereEqualTo("y",Y);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query1 =ParseQuery.getQuery("UserData");
    query.whereEqualTo("entity1",entity1);
    query.whereEqualTo("entity2",entity2);

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> parseObjects, ParseException e) {
            if (null == e) {
                mCountDownLatch.countDown();
            }
        }
    });
    query1.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> parseObjects, ParseException e) {
            if (null == e) {
                mCountDownLatch.countDown();
            }
        }
    });
    try {
        mCountDownLatch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        proceedToApp();
    }
```

You just need to create separate thread from which you will call await().

Answer (score 0):

If you were using JavaScript I would say "Promises are your friend".

Since you're using Java / Android I would suggest you look at "Bolts".

Here's a Blog post from Parse that introduces it:
http://blog.parse.com/2014/10/15/introducing-bolts-for-parse-sdks/

In your case your `onSuccess` would fire the 2nd query or you would replace the `saveTasks` array with a `findTasks` array and save the `findInBackground()` operations.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understood.Can you please Explain?

Comment: if he would start second task in onSuccess these two queries would run sequentially, not simultaneously.

Comment: Yes, he would be better off putting both queries into the array and have it await them both at once. I haven't played with Bolts in Android yet so I'm simply providing a link to learn more about it.